# Magento 1.9 SHOP BY CATEGORY translation not affected

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, category-products, cash-on-delivery, troubleshooting

Magento 1.9 SHOP BY CATEGORY translation not affected how can i translate to french i'm using Porto theme please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the admin, Catalog -> Categories -> Manage Categories, select the French store from the Store Switcher on the left, then click on the category and change the Name field. Make sure you unckech *Use Default Value* checkbox from the right side of the field. If you don't have a multi-store setup, just ignore the part with the store switcher.

Optionally, you might need to re-index *Category Flat Data* from System -> Index Management and clear the cache from System -> Cache Management.

Cheers